# How to access text content using Xpath in Odoo15

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo-15

I am using Odoo15, and I am trying to access the text content in the following XML code :

```
<div t-if="record.type.raw_value == 'product'">
   On hand:  
  <field name="qty_available"/>
  <field name="uom_id"/> 
</div>
```

I have tried using `//div/text()` and also `//div[contains(text(), 'On hand: ')]`  but that did not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What was the result / error? `did not work` is not descriptive enough. Is that the only `div` in the entire XML / page / document?

Comment: For the first one, I got the following error when updating the module :
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/f:/odoo%2015.0.20220206/odoo15/custom/commercial/views/product_views.xml:28, somewhere inside ...
For the second one, I get no error when updating the module but when I access the view it says that : the element cannot be located in the parent view

Answer (score 0):

**Problems**

First, be sure to have valid xml.

`//div/text()`

will select all text()-nodes from all divs, also text()-nodes that only contain white-space.

`//div[contains(text(), 'On hand: ')]`

will probably fail while the `div`-element contains more than one text()-node, and the first argument of the contains()-function can only be `one` string.

**Solutions**

Depending on the variation of the content of that `div` you could use:

`//div[contains(., 'On hand: ')]`

will select any `div` that has somewhere the string 'On hand: '
The `.` in the contains()-function joins all `text()`-nodes into one string

`//div[contains(text()[1], 'On hand: ')]`

will select any `div` that has a first `text()`-node that contains the string 'On hand: '

`//div/text()[contains(., 'On hand: ')]`

will select any `text()`-node that is a direct child of a `div` and that contains the string 'On hand: '

`//div/text()[normalize-space()]`

will select only `text()`-nodes that is a direct child of a `div` that contain more than just white-space